# How to move non-Copy data between enum items

Tags: rust, ownership

I have a Rust enum that represents a state machine. I need to move some data between states (where the data doesn't implement `Copy`). What's a good approach to use?

Basically, I'd like to eliminate the call to `bravo.clone()` in this code. It's disappointing to have to clone that data, when the original is going to be dropped. What I'd rather be doing is something along the lines of `bravo: *bravo` — moving the old value of `bravo` out of `State1` and into `State2`. But I can't do that directly, because that would briefly invalidate the value of `self.state` while constructing `State2`.

```rust
enum MyStateMachine {
    Idle,
    State1 {
        alpha: usize,
        bravo: String,
    },
    // State2 is a superset of State1
    State2 {
        alpha: usize,
        bravo: String,
        charlie: usize,
    },
}

impl MyStateMachine {
    fn to_state2(&mut self, charlie: usize) -> Result<(), String> {
        use MyStateMachine::*;

        match self {
            State1 { alpha, bravo } => {
                *self = State2 {
                    // Copy type moves between states OK
                    alpha: *alpha, 
                     // Non-copy types require a call to .clone()
                    bravo: bravo.clone(),
                    charlie,
                };
                Ok(())
            }
            _ => Err("Must be in State1".into())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do that directly because Rust ensures that `*self` must be valid every single time. Which is good, because what would happen if your program panics somewhere and it has to call `drop()` and your `*self` is inconsistent?

Fortunately your object has a handy `Idle` status that can be used as an intermediate value. The final trick is in [`std::mem::replace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html):

```
impl MyStateMachine {
    fn to_state2(&mut self, charlie: usize) -> Result<(), String> {
        use MyStateMachine::*;

        // take ownership of the old status, installing the dummy Idle
        let old = std::mem::replace(self, Idle);

        match old {
            State1 { alpha, bravo } => {
                //assign the final status
                *self = State2 {
                    alpha: alpha, 
                     // no clone!
                    bravo: bravo,
                    charlie,
                };
                Ok(())
            }
            _ => { 
                // restore old status before returning error
                std::mem::replace(self, old);
                Err("Must be in State1".into())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you didn't have the `Idle` there are other workarounds. For example, you could move out the `bravo` from `self` replacing it with a dummy value, if there is such a value for its type and then build the new state easily. Maybe something like this:

```
impl MyStateMachine {
    fn to_state2(&mut self, charlie: usize) -> Result<(), String> {
        use MyStateMachine::*;

        *self = match self {
            State1 { alpha, bravo } => {
                //steal the value replacing it with a dummy
                //remember that String::new() does not allocate memory
                let bravo = std::mem::replace(bravo, String::new());
                State2 {
                    alpha: *alpha, 
                     // no clone!
                    bravo,
                    charlie,
                }
            }
            _ =>  return Err("Must be in State1".into())
        };
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

If the type of your `brave` does not have a suitable dummy value, you could also replace its type with an `Option<_>` and use `Option::take()` instead of `mem::replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a variation on [rodrigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57615497/939467). I was reluctant to use `mem::replace()` before the `match` statement, because that advances the state before validating that it's OK to change state. So, instead, I used `mem::replace()` just on the non-Copy types.

```rust
impl MyStateMachine {
    fn to_state2(&mut self, charlie: usize) -> Result<(), String> {
        use MyStateMachine::*;

        match self {
            State1 { alpha, bravo: old_bravo } => {
                // Use mem::replace on non-Copy types
                let bravo = std::mem::replace(old_bravo, Default::default());
                *self = State2 {
                    // Copy types can use a simple dereference
                    alpha: *alpha, 
                    bravo, 
                    charlie,
                };
                Ok(())
            }
            _ => return Err("Must be in State1".into())
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the second version of the second option in my answer, isn't it? I edited it quite a few times...

Comment: Yeah. I guess I was looking at an earlier version of your answer. And then you and I came to the same conclusion :-)